# Gremlin: how to get all of the graph structure surrounding a single vertex into a subgraph

Tags: gremlin

I would like to get all of the graph structure surrounding a single vertex into a subgraph.

The [TinkerPop documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#subgraph-step) shows how to do this for a fixed number of traversal steps.

My question: are there any recipes for getting the entire surrounding structure (which may include cycles) without knowing ahead of time how many traversal steps are needed?

---

I have updated this question for the benefit of anyone who might land on this question, here is a gremlin statement that will capture an arbitrary graph structure that surrounds a vertex with id='xxx'

*g.V('xxx').repeat(out().simplePath()).until(outE().count().is(eq(0))).path()*

-- this incorporates Stephen Mallete's suggestion to use simplePath within the repeat step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That example uses `repeat()...times()` but you could easily replace `times()` with `until()` and not know the number of steps ahead of time. See more information in the [Reference Documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#repeat-step) on how `repeat()` works to see how to express different types of flow control and traversal stop conditions.

Comment: That makes sense.  So then, with respect to *cycles*, I should use side effects to accumulate state in a way that allows the algorithm to detect and handle them?

Comment: i think you're saying that you want to filter out paths that cycle - `simplePath()` filter step can help with that.

Comment: Actually, what I am worried about with respect to cycles, is that if I use repeat/until to try to get a subgraph structure that has cycles in it, that the traversal will never complete.   So I am thinking that I will need to use *sack* to store state that can be used to detect cycles and not get *stuck* in them.  Does that make sense?

Comment: That's why I mentioned `simplePath()` - it can filter out cycles in the `repeat()`. http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#simplepath-step

Comment: Ok, great, I will try that.